# DSpace 7 embedding java script code in untyped-item.component.html

Tags: javascript, angular, dspace

I know bootstrap but I don't know angular. The system (DSpace 7) I am dealing with was completely rebuilt using "angular". The problem is that I don't know how to embed the java script, because when I add the code directly to untyped-item.component.html, nothing is displayed.

**JavaScript**

```
<!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style">
<a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_email"></a>
</div>
<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
<!-- AddToAny END -->
```

**untyped-item.component.html:**

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="iiifEnabled">
  <div class="col-12">
    <ds-mirador-viewer id="iiif-viewer"
                   [object]="object"
                   [searchable]="iiifSearchEnabled"
                   [query]="iiifQuery$ | async">
    </ds-mirador-viewer>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <ds-item-page-title-field [item]="object" class="mr-auto">
  </ds-item-page-title-field>
  <div class="pl-2 space-children-mr">
    <ds-dso-page-version-button (newVersionEvent)="onCreateNewVersion()" [dso]="object"
                                [tooltipMsgCreate]="'item.page.version.create'"
                                [tooltipMsgHasDraft]="'item.page.version.hasDraft'"></ds-dso-page-version-button>
    <ds-dso-page-edit-button [pageRoute]="itemPageRoute" [dso]="object" [tooltipMsg]="'item.page.edit'"></ds-dso-page-edit-button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!mediaViewer.image">
      <ds-metadata-field-wrapper [hideIfNoTextContent]="false">
        <ds-thumbnail [thumbnail]="object?.thumbnail | async"></ds-thumbnail>
      </ds-metadata-field-wrapper>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="mediaViewer.image">
      <ds-media-viewer [item]="object" [videoOptions]="mediaViewer.video"></ds-media-viewer>
    </ng-container>
    <span>**JAVA SCRIPT HERE**</span>
<ds-themed-item-page-file-section [item]="object"></ds-themed-item-page-file-section>
    <ds-item-page-date-field [item]="object"></ds-item-page-date-field>
    <ds-metadata-representation-list class="ds-item-page-mixed-author-field"
      [parentItem]="object"
      [itemType]="'Person'"
      [metadataFields]="['dc.contributor.author', 'dc.creator']"
      [label]="'relationships.isAuthorOf' | translate">
    </ds-metadata-representation-list>
    <ds-generic-item-page-field [item]="object"
      [fields]="['journal.title']"
      [label]="'item.page.journal-title'">
    </ds-generic-item-page-field>
    <ds-generic-item-page-field [item]="object"
      [fields]="['journal.identifier.issn']"
      [label]="'item.page.journal-issn'">
    </ds-generic-item-page-field>
    <ds-generic-item-page-field [item]="object"
      [fields]="['journalvolume.identifier.name']"
      [label]="'item.page.volume-title'">
    </ds-generic-item-page-field>
    <ds-generic-item-page-field [item]="object"
      [fields]="['dc.publisher']"
      [label]="'item.page.publisher'">
    </ds-generic-item-page-field>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <ds-item-page-abstract-field [item]="object"></ds-item-page-abstract-field>
    <ds-generic-item-page-field [item]="object"
      [fields]="['dc.description']"
      [label]="'item.page.description'">
    </ds-generic-item-page-field>

    <ds-generic-item-page-field [item]="object"
      [fields]="['dc.subject']"
      [separator]="','"
      [label]="'item.page.subject'">
    </ds-generic-item-page-field>
    <ds-generic-item-page-field [item]="object"
      [fields]="['dc.identifier.citation']"
      [label]="'item.page.citation'">
    </ds-generic-item-page-field>
    <ds-item-page-uri-field [item]="object"
      [fields]="['dc.identifier.uri']"
      [label]="'item.page.uri'">
    </ds-item-page-uri-field>
    <ds-item-page-collections [item]="object"></ds-item-page-collections>
    <div>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" [routerLink]="[itemPageRoute + '/full']" role="button">
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> {{"item.page.link.full" | translate}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**untyped-item.component.ts:**

```
        import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Item } from '../../../../core/shared/item.model';
    import { ViewMode } from '../../../../core/shared/view-mode.model';
    import { listableObjectComponent } from '../../../../shared/object-collection/shared/listable-object/listable-object.decorator';
    import { VersionedItemComponent } from '../versioned-item/versioned-item.component';
    
    /**
     * Component that represents a publication Item page
     */
    
    @listableObjectComponent(Item, ViewMode.StandalonePage)
    @Component({
      selector: 'ds-untyped-item',
      styleUrls: ['./untyped-item.component.scss'],
      templateUrl: './untyped-item.component.html',
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    })
    export class UntypedItemComponent extends VersionedItemComponent {
    
    }
```

What should I add to the file **untyped-item.component.ts** to make the javascript display?

Thanks,

Karol

Comment: There will probably be more to it than that, but to include a javascript file in Angular, edit the angular.json file: there you can add it to the `scripts` section.

Comment: Something like ng-bootstrap makes it much easier to use angular and bootstrap together
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home